# How can you convert a monster into a playable race in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, monsters, races

Alright, I know it's within the rules to create a monster into a playable race. However the method to do so seems to be vague and not well explained. So while previously I asked if it was possible to convert monsters to PC was answered, **it didn't answer how to do so in-depth.**

If I were to use a CP 2 monster as an example like a Boar, how would this translate into a playable race?

Comment: It asks if it can be done, not how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Advanced Race Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8rv2?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Race-Guide) brings us rules on how to build new races and how to qualify each racial trait from existing races (humans, elves, dwarves, etc).

The rules can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races).

Each quality has a RP (*Race Points*) value, and you can balance the racial traits using the total RP the creature has. You can take a high CR monster and move some abilities to racial traits, such as spell-like abilities and some supernatural abilities.

A [Boar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/boar/boar) is an animal, and with their 1-2 int, they would make a *terrible playable race*. But let's turn this boar into an humanoid boar, a **Boarman**.

Our boarmen would likely be either small or medium sized (both 0 RP), and also a **monstrous humanoid (3 RP**, gains darkvision) due to their animalistic features.

They would have a normal base speed (0 RP). I see that a boar is strong and tough, so let's pick the **Flexible (2 RP)** ability score modifiers and apply +2 to strenght and constitution scores.

Boars got natural armor +4, so it would make sense to give our boarman **Natural Armor +1 (2 RP)**. They also got toughness as a bonus feat, so we could use the **Static Bonus Feat (2 RP)** to give our boarmen the same feat.

And finally, boars got a gore natural attack, which could translate as **Natural Attack (1 RP)** to give our boarmen a gore primary attack that will deal 1d6 damage.

and finally, boars got **Scent (4 RP)**.

That's it, a simple boarman race with a total of **14 Race Points**.

Comment: RE: "A Boar is an animal, and with their 1-2 int, they cannot qualify as a playable race." I know that this was a rule (or at least a strong suggestion) in *3.5*, but where is this in *Pathfinder*?

Comment: No rule for that, simply a strong suggestion. Animals cannot take class levels and feats other than the few animal feats, and skills other than the few animal skills. A GM could allow  a PC to play as an animal, but there is no base race point for the animal subtype for the purpose of building races.

Comment: Are you sure about the feats and class levels thing? I know that animal *companions* are limited in their feats, but *all* animals? Likewise, I know that creatures that advance by Hit Dice *should* advance by Hit Dice and…  aha! An edit! Never mind then. `:-)`

Comment: Rules-wise they could even learn how to wield an exotic kusarigama or repeating crossbow (and even cast spells using wisdom or charisma), as those feats have no "minimum logic" requeriment. But the GM is charged with applying common sense and consult the ability scores tables when things seem out of hand.

Comment: The only creatures that seems to not gain feats are Oozes, Plants, Vermin and mindless Undead. If they have 0 or no Intelligence score.